# c# game (xamarin spritekit) optimization

Tags: c#, xamarin, sprite-kit

I write a game. This game isn't very simple, but I didn't suppose that it will take around 95% of CPU. I read much articles about optimization, but it wasn't helpful.

At the moment I have 2d models which contains much children and I have a complicated game logic. I tried to debug and test my code, but i can't understand why... why it takes so much CPU.

Can you give some advices about optimization?

UPD:

Platform: Cross Platform (macOS / iOS) Right now I use macOS, not a simulator

Comment: Are you talking about CPU usage while running an emulator or on a real device? In both ways, it would be helpful to have additional details (Manufacturer, Device Name, Operating System and the version of the OS). I'm pretty sure there is a way to use GPU instead of CPU to render these Models by doing [some research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: before optimization, maybe you should pinpoint what is using CPU this much using profiling tools or disassemblers.

Comment: @mcy thanks, helpful. I will try.

Comment: Is the game even designed to take less CPU? Some games tend to create maximum CPU load on any system and just increase the frame rate in return for more power. This would mean that for any optimization that doesn't address the root cause, the same CPU burn rate would just produce more frames